# Skrollr not working in wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, css, skrollr

I have the following site http://developerace.tk/project1/?page_id=39 I integrated skrollr as shown in their example but the images does not work. Please help.

Comment: A bit more info on what you want and what is going wrong...

Comment: You need to set skrollr's data attributes on the div containing images you want to scroll.

Comment: I need the sections background to be parallax on scroll same as in example http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/classic.html

Comment: @mirceapop can you give me an example for my structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sollution for wordpress.

```
    <section id="id1" class="section numb active" >
<div class="bcg" id="bg1" data-center="background-position: 50% 0px;" data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% 300px;" data-anchor-target="#id1">
<div class="hsContainer" data-center="opacity: 1" data-center-top="opacity: 0" data--100-bottom="opacity: 0;" data-anchor-target="#id1 .hsContent">
<div class="hsContent"><h1>Test</h1></div></div></div>
</section>
```